# Why FM radio app is limited to FM 108

Tags: fm-radio

I just discovered I can listen to FM radio with my phone and a jack cable but I was wondering why is it limited to FM108? I tried another app and it still limited to FM108. The reason I'm asking this is that I would like to receive the international space station SSTV signal but the frequency is FM 145.8 or something like that. My device is an LG G6.

Comment: The radio is supposed to use the headphones as an antenna. Have you tried with any other headphones? It is possible the ones you have are giving a signal that is only picking up the strongest station.

Comment: The FM frequencies go from 88 to 108 MHz that's why your apps are limited to 108 MHz.

Comment: Is there any app that allows using higher frequency or its just the FM chip on the phone?

Comment: I think this is more a legal limitation. AFAIK the frequencies beyond the standard FM range are/were used in some countries by Police and other security relevant public services. Therefore access to those frequencies is disabled by default.

Comment: To confirm Reddy's comment, [standard FM radio broadcasting is between 87.5-108 MHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_broadcasting#FM). It's also kind of similar for "why don't radio tuner on cars also cover that range". Perhaps there are apps that allow arbitrary frequency, but I don't have any clue. You might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for specialized SE on this specific purpose.